# Using Cookies to set an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to create a script that when the user opens the site he or she will be welcomed by a prompt and after an alert will say welcome but also what is entered in the prompt will set a cookie for 1 minute the problems I'm facing are:
1. The alert does not show up
2. The Cookie will not set

```
function checkCookie()
{
    var username=getCookie("username");
    if (username!=null && username!="") {
        alert("Welcome again "+ username);  
    }
    else {
        username=prompt("Please input name:","");
        if (username !=null && username!="") {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }
}
function setCookie (cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime (d.getTime()+ (10*1000));
    var expires ="; expires= "+ d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires; +"; path /";
}
function getCookie(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++){
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }   
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0){
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging to see which part of the code why isn't working. You can try with  console.log()  ?

Comment: there was no error in the console

Comment: I bet nothing is wrong with your code it's just the expiration time being so low ( just 10 seconds)

Comment: no i did it on purpose my problem is either with the chrome browser or something else

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `var expires ="; expires= "+ d.toGMTString();` with `var expires ="; expires= "+ d.toUTCString();`

The expire time is saved as Unix timestamp.

**Edit:**
You need to execute the function checkCookie too. I thought that was obvious.

https://jsfiddle.net/osgohu5b/

Comment: my problems is the loop does not shwo the alert

Comment: What loop do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle of your code: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/19yp8ucd/3/ .
It works fine. You just need to call checkCookie() function.

```
checkCookie();
```

See the last line in .js of the fiddle.

Also, you're not using the number of days in your setCookie() function. You can check a good implementation of setCookie(), getCookie(), eraseCookie() here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596/3946520